LDAP groupSearchFilter with new Spring Security
I used to have following working code in old version of my application:
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
[...]
@Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource contextSource =
                new DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource(properties.getLdapServerUrl());
        contextSource.afterPropertiesSet();
        contextSource.setUrl(properties.getLdapServerUrl());
        contextSource.setUserDn(properties.getManagerLogin());
        contextSource.setPassword(properties.getManagerPassword());

        auth.ldapAuthentication().userSearchFilter(properties.getUserSearchFilter())
                .userSearchBase(properties.getUserSearchBase())
                .groupSearchFilter(properties.getGroupSearchFilter())
                .groupRoleAttribute(properties.getGroupRoleAttribute())
                .ldapAuthoritiesPopulator(getCustomLdapAuthoritiesPopulatorBean())
                .contextSource(contextSource);
    }

Now, according to documentation I've changed it to:
public class SecurityConfiguration {
[...]
@Bean
    AuthenticationManager ldapAuthenticationManager() {
        DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource contextSource =
                new DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource(properties.getLdapServerUrl());
        contextSource.afterPropertiesSet();
        contextSource.setUrl(properties.getLdapServerUrl());
        contextSource.setUserDn(properties.getManagerLogin());
        contextSource.setPassword(properties.getManagerPassword());

        LdapBindAuthenticationManagerFactory factory = new LdapBindAuthenticationManagerFactory(contextSource);

        factory.setUserSearchFilter(properties.getUserSearchFilter());
        factory.setUserSearchBase(properties.getUserSearchBase());
/*
                .groupSearchFilter(properties.getGroupSearchFilter())
                .groupRoleAttribute(properties.getGroupRoleAttribute())
*/
        factory.setLdapAuthoritiesPopulator(getCustomLdapAuthoritiesPopulatorBean());
        return factory.createAuthenticationManager();
    }

The factory class does not have methods that relate to ldap groups. So, how can I update my code so it can use my groupSearchFilter and groupRoleAttribute properties?
